# flutter admob/webview showing blank page after app resume from background

Tags: android, flutter, webview, admob

BannerAd showings blank black page after the application is restored from the background.
As far as I know, google_mobile_ads is using webview_flutter package in flutter. As expected, the same problem occurs with the webview when restored from the background. All functionality in admob/webview (like clicking or scrolling) works fine, it just renders black blank. Even if I build a new project with only a ad, the problem still exists.

The code below contains just one simple BannerAd that showings a blank page after the application is restored from the background.
(in flutter 3.16.3 / Pixel 7 Pro)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

void main(){
    runApp(MaterialApp(home:AD()));
}

class AD extends StatefulWidget{
    @override
    State createState()=>_AD();
}
class _AD extends State<AD>{
    BannerAd?_ADBANNER;
    final ValueNotifier<bool>_READY=ValueNotifier<bool>(false);

    @override
    void initState(){
        super.initState();
        MobileAds.instance.initialize();
        if(null==_ADBANNER)
        _ADBANNER=
        BannerAd(
            adUnitId:'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111',
            size:AdSize.banner,
            request:AdRequest(),
            listener:BannerAdListener(
                onAdLoaded:(AD){
                    debugPrint('Ad loaded');
                    if(!_READY.value)
                    _READY.value=true;
                },
                onAdFailedToLoad:(AD,E){
                    debugPrint('Ad failed to load: $E');
                    _READY.value=false;
                    AD.dispose();
                },
            ),
        )
        ..load();
    }

    @override
    void dispose(){
        _READY.value=false;
        _ADBANNER?.dispose();
        debugPrint('Ad disposed');
        super.dispose();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(CTX){
        return
        ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
            valueListenable:_READY,
            builder:(CTX,V,_){
                debugPrint('LISTEN');

                if(V)
                return
                Container(
                    alignment:Alignment.center,
                    color:Colors.white,
                    child:
                    AdWidget(ad:_ADBANNER!),
                );

                else
                return
                Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
        );
    }
}
```

what am I missing in this code??

[image]

PS: This is only happen in my pixel 7 pro and mi a1 phone, not in emulator, and no error in debug console at all. I tried using bannerAds and webview at the same time, when slivergrid comes into the viewport, bannerAds shows crazy display errors, duplicating the webview screen.

[image]

Comment: Got the same issue, on Samsung phones with Android14.
Did you find any solution/explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

For the record :

- This issue was identified on Flutter's Github. It impacts Samsung and Pixels phones
- A bugfix was developed on Flutter's engine [in this commit](https://github.com/flutter/engine/commit/9fd72bd94900618088ac94f713b85500e1947195) and should be part of one of the next releases (probably Flutter 3.20)

So if you ever encounter this issue in the future, please upgrade your Flutter's version first